# Queue.join() doesn't unblock

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm trying to write a Python script for parallel crawling of a website. I made a prototype that would allow me to crawl to depth one.

However, `join()` doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
from threading import Thread
import Queue
import urllib2
import re
from BeautifulSoup import *
from urlparse import urljoin


def doWork():
    while True:
        try:
            myUrl = q_start.get(False)
        except:
            continue
        try:
            c=urllib2.urlopen(myUrl)
        except:
            continue
        soup = BeautifulSoup(c.read())
        links = soup('a')
        for link in links:
            if('href' in dict(link.attrs)):
                url = urljoin(myUrl,link['href'])
                if url.find("'")!=-1: continue
                url=url.split('#')[0]
                if url[0:4] == 'http':
                    print url
                    q_new.put(url)




q_start = Queue.Queue()

q_new = Queue.Queue()



for i in range(20):
        t = Thread(target=doWork)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()


q_start.put("http://google.com")
print "loading"
q_start.join()
print "end"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`join()` will block until `task_done()` has been called as many times as items have been enqueued](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.task_done).

You don't call `task_done()`, thus `join()` blocks.  In the code you provide, the right place to call this is at the very end of your `doWork` loop:

```
def doWork():
  while True:
    task = start_q.get(False)
    ...
    for subtask in processed(task):
      ...
    start_q.task_done()  # tell the producer we completed a task
```